# Meaning of the Dollar symbol ($) in the log messages

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, syntax

```
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    java.util.HashMap$HashIterator(HashMap.java:806)

    com.cimba.gsr.fragments.SessionsFragment(SessionsFragment.java:233)

    com.cimba.gsr.fragments.SessionsFragment$4(SessionsFragment.java:201)
```

Sometime in log output after a class name there is a Dollor symbol ($) in the message what does that mean? I thought it's the method name or the variable name in the class that caused the exception but in this case it doesn't make sense (SessionsFragment$4 it can't be the name of a method or variable).
so what is it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `$` is a separator that indicates that there is a nested class `HashIterator` inside the `HashMap` class, and that there is an anonymous inner class (the fourth one, it looks like) inside the `SessionsFragment` class.

[This site explains](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077489/core-java/java-tip-124--trace-your-steps-in-java-1-4.html) the `$` separator.

> ```
> Filename: StackTrace.java
>
> Line number: 267
> Package name: boo.hoo
> Full class name: boo.hoo.StackTrace$FirstNested$SecondNested
> Simple class name: StackTrace$FirstNested$SecondNested
> Unmunged class name: StackTrace.FirstNested.SecondNested
> Direct class name: SecondNested
> Method name: <init>
> Native method?: false
> toString():
> boo.hoo.StackTrace$FirstNested$SecondNested.<init>(StackTrace.java:267)
> ```
>
> The nested classes are distinguished from the higher-level nested classes and from the top-level class by using the dollar sign character ($). So, technically, the "simple" name of the second nested class is StackTrace$FirstNested$SecondNested.