# What does $ symbol signify in Android

Tags: android, proguard

I have an Exception saying my classname$a.a() method was invoked on a null object reference. I don't understand what the $ symbol signifies. I used Proguard for mapping but the file was overwritten and now my firebase crash logs show this exception message

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.package.TestClass$a.a()' on a null object reference
com.package.TestClass.h ()
com.package.TestClass.a ()
com.package.TestClass.onStartCommand ()
android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs (ActivityThread.java:3347)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1595)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6165)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:888)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Comment: you have an inner interface defined  in TestClass.. $sign indicates the inner class or interface.. As per the crash log its any interface created in your TestClass with any method.. some one is trying to call the method of your inner interface defined in TestClass with null object

Comment: you might forgot to register this interface ,, your inteface need to be implemented or should be anonymously initialsed and passed .. And your TestClass seems like a Service class

Answer (score 0):

The $ is a separator that indicates that there is a nested class.
You can read more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919722/meaning-of-the-dollar-symbol-in-the-log-messages).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this answer which nicely explains this. [Meaning of the Dollar symbol ($) in the log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919793/3568660)

Note: Can not post comment due to < 50 reputation.