# What does $ symbol mean in Java/Android API calls?

Tags: java, android, androguard

I am collecting API calls from the source code of Android apps using Androguard. Some of the retrieved API calls have a $ symbol in their call description, such as: `Ljava/util/Locale$LanguageRange/<init>` or `Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector$Builder/setBarcodeFormats`, whereas the vast majority of them do not have this dollar symbol included. For instance, `Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/Tracker/<init>`.

The $ symbol is to denote variable references in some programming but it is strange to find it in an API call reference. How can I interpret it here? What does the $ symbol mean in this context of API call tracing?

Comment: BarcodeDetector$Builder <-- Builder is an inner class in this case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919722/meaning-of-the-dollar-symbol-in-the-log-messages

Answer (score 4):

In this case it represents a nested class.

So for the example of [`BarcodeDetector$Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector.Builder), it is referring to the `Builder` class which is a class within `BarcodeDetector`.

Comment: Thanks! So I can assume that `Builder` is then a child class of `BarcodeDetector`, thus inheriting from the parent class `BarcodeDetector`?

Comment: Not quite, `Builder` wouldn't have to inherit from `BarcodeDetector`, it's just nested within. You can take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for some more clarity.